# JavaFX 2.0: Flowpane should automaticly resize when parental element does

Tags: layout, resize, autosize, javafx-2

In JavaFX 1.x, where I've used the FX-Script to setup the Scene, I had the bind keyword:

[Dynamic/instant resize in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391373/dynamic-instant-resize-in-javafx)

How can I have the same behavior in 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want automatic resize, you should do something like this

```
private BorderPane root;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
   root = new BorderPane();
    //ROOT SHOULD BE ONE OF THE LAYOUTS : BorderPane, HBox, VBox, StackPane,     
    //GridPane, FlowPane
    scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
    root.setCenter(new Label("sample label"));
}
```

I have tried only with BorderPane and it works. Also if you want to create custom
component, your class should extend one of layouts. Automatic resize won't work if your component extends Pane or Group

I think this will help to you.

Best regards
Sandro

Answer (score 5):

I've just found the answer on another plattform:

It is as easy as

```
FlowPane layout=new FlowPane();
layout.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
layout.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
```

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for a way to let my FlowPane grow vertically to fit in a VBox. Of course VBox.setVGrow would not work on a FlowPane.  This technique does. I wonder where you found this.

Answer (score 0):

If your flow pane has margins, you need perhaps something like this:

```
  innerHorizontalFlowPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(
      Bindings.add(-50, stage.widthProperty()))
```